# Hybrid Django Application - REST API Authentication

Tags: javascript, python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and have built a basic application (Django 3.1) which uses session authentication and a simple login page (username + password) to login a django user. It works fine. I would like to use javascript (vue.js) on pages accessible to the logged in user to call Django REST APIs, hosted on the same Django application.

Despite lots of googling, no one seems to give a clear authentication example of a hybrid Django app, augmented with APIs. I have used lots of APIs before so am familiar with the authentication options. **My issue is how to get credentials to the javascript loaded by django templates in a secure manner.**

IDEALLY I would like:

1. User logs in with username/password
2. django redirects to PAGE B, **AUTOMAGICALLY SOMEHOW** inserting user's token into a cookie/sessionStorage
3. A javascript function on PAGE B gets credentials from cookie/sessionStorage and calls API (using all the various options supported by django-rest-framework)

My Questions:

Question 1 ==> in my do_login view function (below), after successful authentication with Djangos inbuilt **login** method, do I need to create a cookie in HttpResponse (e.g. token=XXXXXXX), so javascript can access it? Is this secure?

```
    def do_login(request):
       ....
       login(request, user)
       ...
       #create token here and return to user somehow in cookie/sessionStorage
       return render(request, 'hello/logged_in_ok.html')
```

So my javascript can do **something** like this (demo code only):

```
function onButtonClick(){
    let token = sesssionStorage.getItem("django_gave_me_this_token");
    let response = callGetAPISomehow(token, "https://demo/rest/api/account/1")
    .....
}
```

Question 2 ==> Most view methods finish up with:

```
    return render(request, 'blah/blah.html', {'data': blah})
```

How do I set the cookie in the response this way? There is no response object to access.

All help appreciated

Comment: Are you using Django REST framework? If you're using Django's default sessions configuration, sessions through AJAX should work out of the box (See the docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/)

Comment: Yes, the Django REST framework